# How to ignore lid switch action?

Tags: linux, configuration, hardware, acpi

When I close the lid of my laptop, the computer shuts down immediately and won't power on again. I need to take a screwdriver and disconnect-reconnect the battery in order to make it power on.

I really want Linux to ignore the lid switch.

I already tried a lot of answers on stack overflow but none works. What I tried:

- Put `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
- `systemd-inhibit --what=handle-lid-switch sleep 1d`
- `cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep -i lid` does throw nothing
- Put `IgnoreLid=true` in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`
- `systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target`
- `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` does not exist
- In `gconf-editor`, in `apps > gnome-power-manager > buttons`, set `lid_ac` and `lid_battery` to `nothing`

I reboot my computer after changing those config files to be sure all services are restarted.

How is this possible? What could I try next in order to make the lid switch be ignored?

I'm using Ubuntu with Cinnamon.

Comment: Does it work reliably with any other operating systems? Without confirmation either way, this looks more like a hardware problem than an OS problem

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is actually pretty easy... but was really difficult to find.

1. Find the node for the lid device in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`:

```
grep LID /proc/acpi/wakeup
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

(the node is 'PNP0C0D:00')

2. As root, create an `rc.local` file (with the contents below) that will disable the device at boot time.  Make this file executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo PNP0C0D:00 > /sys/bus/acpi/drivers/button/unbind
```

If you're using systemd, it should automatically detect this and execute it on boot.  This completely disables the switch and allows the laptop to boot even with the lid closed.

You can look way down at the bottom of this page for some more information: https://dev1galaxy.org/viewtopic.php?id=2021

Comment: More recent distributions don't use rc.local by default.  After creating the `/etc/rc.local` file as described above, re-enable its use with:
  1. Put this in `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service`: ```[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target```
  2. `systemctl enable rc-local`