# Ignore Lid Switch Action

Tags: debian, gnome

I have the same problem like this guy:

[How to ignore lid switch action?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389603/how-to-ignore-lid-switch-action)

Do you have other solutions?

Comment: lid switch comes in via ACPI so attack the system ACPI  config and make it a no-op,  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=72779

Comment: People may need a bit more information to be able to help. Have you tried everything in that post? Get any errors while doing so? Tried anything else that may give some more feedback? Hopefully someone may be able to help.

Comment: @Jasen I am sorry, but I don't understand it. Can you say me, what I should do?

Comment: @Guy I tried everything except gconf-editor.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sudo chmod 000 /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
```

that'll disable the lid acpi event. (well, it does here)

to re-enable

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
```

Comment: I am sorry, I forget my e-mail address in first account. Folder acpi doesn't exist.