# looking for the settings that causes Debian to suspend when laptop lid is closed

Tags: debian, suspend

When I close my laptop lid while am on a console and not in a graphical environment, my Debian-laptop goes to a state of suspend (hard disk and fan turn off, laptop's half-moon LED turns on). I like my system behaving in such a way but I have never set it up this way and would like to know where and what setting is causing this?

Some people in certain forums hint to `HandleLidSwitch` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` but these two lines in the file containing it are commented out on my system.

Answer (score 2):

For systemd users there is a setting in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

`HandleLidSwitch`

If you put `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` it will disable the switch.

You will need to restart systemd-logind daemon.

`$ sudo service systemd-logind restart`

---

For more low level, kernel solution: (found here: [How to ignore lid switch action?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389603/how-to-ignore-lid-switch-action) and here: [how to completely disable laptop lid detection?](https://dev1galaxy.org/viewtopic.php?id=2021) )

find node for the lid:

```
# grep LID /proc/acpi/wakeup
LID       S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

The node is `PNP0C0D:00` here. Write it to `/sys/bus/acpi/drivers/button/unbind`

like that:

```
# grep LID /proc/acpi/wakeup | sed -e 's/^.*platform://' > /sys/bus/acpi/drivers/button/unbind
```

For permanent effect you can put it in `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/rc5.d` wherever your startup scrips are. 5 in `rc5.d` is your desired runlevel you use; can be found out with `$ who -r`)

*Important note*: Test this one first as for me it disabled suspending when I close lid - that is fine, but it still turns off screen and to get it back I needed to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to terminal and run `pm-suspend` and then unsuspend it with home button. But I hope it will work for you.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.

As I wrote in my original post, it is not systemd providing this feature on my system. After all, I am using SysV init instead of systemd.

Comment: I didn't read that properly, sorry, but I found something for you. Hopefully will work. Check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, tansy, that stops my laptop from suspending when the lid is closed.

But I would also like to know what is the command that my Debian executes for suspending when lid is closed. I can find it in none of the files that we needed to touch for deactivating it...

Comment: Unbinding it in /proc is kernel thing, so to answer this you would need to dig in the kernel sources. I don't think there is a command behind that. That's why it's so problematic.

But anyway, I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: Just to confirm that thesis - there is a page where one can report problems with kernel during suspending/hibernating: [Debugging kernel hibernate](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelHibernate).