# Linux cli: disable sleep when laptop lid closed

Tags: debian, power-management, sleep

I have no systemd on my debian based distro (antix) and I also have no desktop environment.
How can i make my laptop to only blank (or disable) screen when lid is closed, instead of suspending as well as keeping suspend button work properly

Comment: It probably depends on whatever init you are using.

Answer (score 7):

##### Disabling the lid completely.

First, you need to find out the path of your lid switch. This can be done by checking the listing of wakeup-capable processes:

```bash
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

In the output one of the lines will correspond to the lid and will look similar to the following output (likely will be the same):

```
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

In order to disable the lid switch completely at kernel level you can use the `unbind` feature of the kernel.(change the `PNP0C0D:00` path to the one corresponding to your lid ):

```
echo 'PNP0C0D:00' | sudo tee /sys/bus/acpi/drivers/button/unbind
```

Once you confirm the lid is indeed disabled you can just add that command to `/etc/rc.local` to have it execute at boot.

##### Making the screen blank after closing the lid

This will be slightly more complex, as you will need to specify `udev` rules in order to have one event (lid) trigger another (disabling screen).

First you will need to find out the path pointing to the internal display of your laptop. It is best to first test the brightness control of the backlight instead of the enabling/disabling of the entire display.

There is a sys path pointing to the backlight controls, and on most laptops it can be accessed by  `cd /sys/class/backlight/*/`

Inside of that sysfs folder you should see a list of control files resembling the following:

```bash
./actual_brightness
./bl_power
./brightness
./max_brightness
./power/async
./power/autosuspend_delay_ms
./power/control
./power/runtime_active_kids
./power/runtime_active_time
./power/runtime_enabled
./power/runtime_status
./power/runtime_suspended_time
./power/runtime_usage
./scale
./type
./uevent
```

Along with directory paths to `device`, `power` , `subsystem` etc.

The `brightness`, and `max_brightness` should correspond to the current setting and the max limit of the range. You should be able to control the brightness of your laptop display itself using `echo` and giving it another value, like so:

```bash
echo "100" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
```

Once you establish that the brightness control indeed works as intented from the cli, report back and I'll explain how one can monitor for the lid closing event to trigger the appropriate udev rule.

Comment: also acpid can be used for more complex behaviour, it runs a script on acpi events

Comment: Brightness control works, but it only makes screen dim. My laptop automatically blanks screen in inactivity for long times so its fine. How do I setup this command to run when lid closed?

Comment: Sorry for the dalay but I somehow missed the comment notification. Actually if your laptop screen already blanks itself out after period of inactivity then going with option 1 (disabling the Lid through ACPI ) may actually be the best solution. The seemingly simply action of closing the lid is one of the worst ones to manage with udev rules, as no consensus has ever been reached on what its base purpose should be, there is no accepted standard among laptop manufacturers(HP,Lenovo), and it is known to cause alot of problems like blank screen, frozen touchpad/keyboard, on wakeup, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be easily configured via `systemd`. The [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#Power_management) sums it up pretty nicely:

> `systemd` handles some power-related ACPI events, whose actions can be configured in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` or `/etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/*.conf` — see [logind.conf(5)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/logind.conf.5). On systems with no dedicated power manager, this may replace the acpid daemon which is usually used to react to these ACPI events.

Make sure the values `HandleLidSwitch`, `HandleLidSwitchDocked` and `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower` are all set to `ignore` in the config file.

Note the much older but similar answer/question at [How to ignore lid switch action?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389603/how-to-ignore-lid-switch-action)